# Not able to access the methods from secure wcf rest service

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl

I have a running wcf rest service hosted on IIS. I have successfully added the .x509 certificates to the client and the server and it works fine.As it is a secure service it is accessed using https **The problem I am facing is that I am not able to access any of the methods from the service it keeps throwing 404 error however when I browse the service from IIS using https link it open the WSDL fine but throws 404 error while accessing any of the methods**.
Here is my Interface implementation of a method from the service.

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestDemo
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/DoWork/{name}")]
        string DoWork(string name);
    }
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestDemo.RestDemo" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost/RestDemo/RestDemo.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestDemo.IRestDemo" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!--<identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>-->

        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="RestDemo.IRestDemo" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="web" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">

          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />

          </security>

        </binding>

      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">

          <!--<serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"
                             trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />

            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="ServerCertificate"
              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              storeName="My"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>-->
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="/RestDemo.svc" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">

          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint

   crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: How are you accessing the methods? Are you calling via code, or browsing to your service?

Comment: @ Wibbler: I am browsing from IIS through https link and it opens the wsdl fine but when I try to  access the methods it throws 404.